# E-mail html responsive for mobiles

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsiveness

I would like to get some help with my e-mail html's that my app will send automatically to my customers. I have one problem. The html e-mails are not responsive on mobile devices. It looks great when someone is opening the email on web, but when someone is using a mobile e-mail app or opening it on web on mobile device it is not responsive. Could you please help me to edit this code that i will attach in this quote? Would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

```
<html lang="en"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
   xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no,address=no,email=no,date=no,url=no">
      <meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
      <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light">
      <title></title>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <xml>
         <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
         </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
      <![endif]-->
      <!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
      <!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 23 - 41 can be safely removed. -->
      <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
      <!--[if mso]>
      <style>
         * {
         font-family: helvetica !important;
         }
      </style>
      <![endif]-->
      <!--[if !mso]>
      <!-->
         <!-- insert web font reference, eg: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
      <!--
         <![endif]-->
      <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->
      <!-- CSS Reset : BEGIN -->
      <style>
         /* What it does: Tells the email client that only light styles are provided but the client can transform them to dark. A duplicate of meta color-scheme meta tag above. */
         :root {
         color-scheme: light;
         supported-color-schemes: light;
         }
         /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
         /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
         html,
         body {
         margin: 0 auto !important;
         padding: 0 !important;
         height: 100% !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
         * {
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         }
         /* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
         div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
         margin: 0 !important;
         }
         /* What it does: forces Samsung Android mail clients to use the entire viewport */
         #MessageViewBody, #MessageWebViewDiv{
         width: 100% !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
         table,
         td {
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. */
         table {
         border-spacing: 0 !important;
         border-collapse: collapse !important;
         table-layout: fixed !important;
         margin: 0 auto !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
         img {
         -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
         }
         anuluj {
         -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
         }
         /* What it does: Prevents Windows 10 Mail from underlining links despite inline CSS. Styles for underlined links should be inline. */
         a {
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         /* What it does: A work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links. */
         a[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
         .unstyle-auto-detected-links a,
         .aBn {
         border-bottom: 0 !important;
         cursor: default !important;
         color: inherit !important;
         text-decoration: none !important;
         font-size: inherit !important;
         font-family: inherit !important;
         font-weight: inherit !important;
         line-height: inherit !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying a download button on large, non-linked images. */
         .a6S {
         display: none !important;
         opacity: 0.01 !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Prevents Gmail from changing the text color in conversation threads. */
         .im {
         color: inherit !important;
         }
         /* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
         img.g-img + div {
         display: none !important;
         }
         /* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
         /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */
         /* iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C, and 5SE */
         @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {
         u ~ div .email-container {
         min-width: 320px !important;
         }
         }
         /* iPhone 6, 6S, 7, 8, and X */
         @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {
         u ~ div .email-container {
         min-width: 375px !important;
         }
         }
         /* iPhone 6+, 7+, and 8+ */
         @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) {
         u ~ div .email-container {
         min-width: 414px !important;
         }
         }
      </style>
      <!-- CSS Reset : END -->
      <!-- Progressive Enhancements : BEGIN -->
      <style>
         /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
         .button-td,
         .button-a {
         transition: all 100ms ease-in;
         }
         .button-td-primary:hover,
         .button-a-primary:hover {
         background: #555555 !important;
         border-color: #555555 !important;
         }
         /* Media Queries */
         @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
         /* What it does: Adjust typography on small screens to improve readability */
         .email-container p {
         font-size: 17px !important;
         }
         }
      </style>
      <!-- Progressive Enhancements : END -->
   </head>
   <!--
      The email background color (#222222) is defined in three places:
      1. body tag: for most email clients
      2. center tag: for Gmail and Inbox mobile apps and web versions of Gmail, GSuite, Inbox, Yahoo, AOL, Libero, Comcast, freenet, Mail.ru, Orange.fr
      3. mso conditional: For Windows 10 Mail
      -->
   <body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #222222;">
      <center role="article" aria-roledescription="email" lang="en" style="width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
         <!--[if mso | IE]>
         <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #222222;">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <![endif]-->
                  <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
                  <div style="max-height:0; overflow:hidden; mso-hide:all;" aria-hidden="true">
                     Podsumowanie zakończonej pracy.
                  </div>
                  <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->
                  <!-- Create white space after the desired preview text so email clients don’t pull other distracting text into the inbox preview. Extend as necessary. -->
                  <!-- Preview Text Spacing Hack : BEGIN -->
                  <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: helvetica;">
                     &zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;
                  </div>
                  <!-- Preview Text Spacing Hack : END -->
                  <!--
                     Set the email width. Defined in two places:
                     1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 600px.
                     2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 600px width.
                     -->
                  <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
                     <!--[if mso]>
                     <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <![endif]-->
                              <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
                              <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin: auto;">
                                 <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="line-height:10px; padding:48px 0px 16px 0px;">
                                          <img src="/130x32.png" width="81" height="20" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="height: auto; background: #FFFFFF; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #FFFFFF;">
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Email Header : END -->
                                    <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <!-- Hero Image, Flush : END -->
                                    <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                                          <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td style="padding: 0px; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
                                                      <h1 style= "margin: 0 0 10px 0; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px; color: #484848; font-weight: normal;">
                                                         <strong>Zakończono pracę.</strong>
                                                      </h1>
                                                      <br>
                                                      <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 18px">Gratulacje, tak trzymaj! Poniżej przesyłamy podsumowanie.</p>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->
                                    <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #ffffff;">
                                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td valign="top" width="50%">
                                                      <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <br>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td style="text-align: left; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #484848; padding: 20px 0px 10px 00px;">
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0;">
                                                                  <h4 style="text-align: inherit">{{job_title}}</h4>
                                                                  </p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 14px; ">Rozpoczęto</p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; ">Zakończono</p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; ">
                                                                     <strong>Czas pracy</strong>
                                                                  </p>
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td valign="top" width="50%">
                                                      <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <br>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td style="text-align: left; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #484848; padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                                                  <p style="margin:0;">
                                                                  <h4 style="text-align: right; color:#484848">{{job_date}}</h4>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 14px; ">{{job_start}}</p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 14px; ">{{job_end}}</p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; text-align: right; ">
                                                                     <strong>{{job_duration}}</strong>
                                                                  </p>
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                          <hr width="100%" size="1" align="center" color="#CECECE">
                                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td valign="top" width="50%">
                                                      <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <br>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td style="text-align: left; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #484848; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                  <p style="margin: -15px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 18px; ">Zleceniodawca</p>
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td valign="top" width="50%">
                                                      <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <br>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td style="text-align: left; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #484848; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                  <p style="margin: -15px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 18px; text-align: right; ">{{taskposter_name}}.</p>
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                          <hr width="100%" size="1" align="center" color="#CECECE">
                                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td valign="top" width="50%">
                                                      <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <br>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td style="text-align: left; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #484848; padding: 0px 0px 0;">
                                                                  <p style="margin: -10 0 0 0;">
                                                                  <h4 style="text-align: inherit; ">Twój zarobek</h4>
                                                                  </p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; ">Cena usługi</p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; ">Opłata serwisowa</p>
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td valign="top" width="50%">
                                                      <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <br>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td style="text-align: left; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #484848; padding: 0px 0px 0;">
                                                                  <p style="margin:-10;">
                                                                  <h4 style="text-align: right; color: #77CB74"">{{job_earnings}}</h4>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 14px; ">{{job_price}}</p>
                                                                  <p style="margin: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 14px; ">{{serive_fee}}</p>
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->
                                    <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
                                    <tr>
                                       <td aria-hidden="true" height="40" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;">
                                          &nbsp;
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Clear Spacer : END -->
                                    <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN -->
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- 1 Column Text : END -->
                     </table>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- Email Body : END -->
         <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="width: 100% !important;">
         <tr>
         <td align="left" valign="top" width="600px" height="1" style="background-color: #cecece; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px;">
         <!--[if gte mso 15]>&nbsp;
         <![endif]-->
         </td>
         </tr>
         <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin: auto;">
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: helvetica;  font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; color: #9A9BA5;">
         Wysłano prosto z ♥ Stepapp
         <br>
         <span class="unstyle-auto-detected-links">Stepapp sp. z o.o. Pokorna 2, 01-500 Warszawa</span>
         <br>
         <a class="Unsubscribe--unsubscribeLink" href="{{{unsubscribe}}}" target="_blank" style="color:#9A9BA5">
         <u>Anuluj subskrypcję</u>
         </a>
         <br></br>
         <br></br>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- Email Footer : END -->
         </div>
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is responsive already, not sure what you're trying to achieve. Please can you update your question including the relevant sections that you are struggling with and be more specific with your question. See how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I assume this code has been copied from elsewhere, what steps have you taken to edit the code, what results were expected and what results were achieved?

Comment: Hey! Thank you for fast answer! I dont know what to say. My python developer pasted that code into our auto-sender and he said that the e-mails are not responsive on mobile :(. When he opened the email on ios original inbox app, the e-mail layout was out of screen.

Comment: Sadly there is no easy way to fix this. For email layouts its best to stick to simple designs and use something like [zurb mail foundation](https://get.foundation/emails/docs/sass-guide.html) ... And also always use some email preview app like [litmus live testin](https://www.litmus.com/email-testing/) Litmus is quite pricy, you can also google for free alternatives, but you should use something like this constantly for developing mails